# Recursive for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, recursion

I am struggling to code this recursive program and wondering if anyone could help.

I want to code this recursive equation:

```
for k=1,2,...

beta(k)=k-sum_(i=0)^(k-1)Kchoosei*beta(i)*exp(-i(k-i))
```

I've done it the manual way in R but would like to put it in a function.

```
beta0<-0

beta1<-1-choose(1,0)*beta0*exp(-0*lambdaL*(1-0))
beta2<-2-choose(2,0)*beta0*exp(-0*lambdaL*(2-0))-choose(2,1)*beta1*exp(-1*lambdaL*(2-1))
beta3<-3-choose(3,0)*beta0*exp(-0*lambdaL*(3-0))-choose(3,1)*beta1*exp(-1*lambdaL*(3-1))-choose(3,2)*beta2*exp(-2*lambdaL*(3-2))
beta4<-4-choose(4,0)*beta0*exp(-0*lambdaL*(4-0))-choose(4,1)*beta1*exp(-1*lambdaL*(4-1))-choose(4,2)*beta2*exp(-2*lambdaL*(4-2))-choose(4,3)*beta3*exp(-3*lambdaL*(4-3))
```

Comment: lambdaL is not defined and not in your general equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just define a second loop for the sum. Note that the indexing here begins with `1` rather than `0` which leads to an "index shift".

```
beta = numeric()
beta[1] <- 0

for (k in 1:10){
  beta[k+1] <- k
  for (i in 0:(k-1))
    beta[k+1] <- beta[k+1] - choose(k, i)*beta[i+1]*exp(-i*(k-i))
}

beta
# [1] 0.000000 1.000000 1.264241 2.080705 3.247551 4.528104 5.748673
# [8] 6.876234 7.941197 8.972749 9.987645
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 2 functions, because you need every previous value of beta as an input, and yet you need only one output. Here's what I propose (to adjust with your lambaL, as there's some ambiguity in your post, it works with `LambdaL == 1`):

```
beta_vec <- function(k){
  if(k == 0) 0 else {
    beta_vec_old <- beta_vec(k-1)
    c(beta_vec_old,sum(sapply(0:(k-1),function(i){1-choose(k,i)*beta_vec_old[i+1]*exp(-i*(k-i))})))
}}

beta <- function(k){
  tail(beta_vec(k),1)  
}

# > beta_vec(5)
# [1] 0.000000 1.000000 1.264241 2.080705 3.247551 4.528104
# > beta(5)
# [1] 4.528104
```

(edited for typo in code)