# Summing in a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, sum

I'm struggling to work out how to code this sum in R; I'm guessing we can use a for loop somehow but can't get my head around it.

The equation I am trying to code is:

> n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}choose(n-1,k)*beta_k*exp(k*L*n-k) for n=1,2,..

[image: Math Latex formula]

where:

1. beta_k is a vector I already have
2. L is a constant.

I've coded this manually but would like to put it into some kind of for loop.

```
mu3<-3-choose(2,1)*beta1*exp(-1*lambdaL*(3-1))-choose(2,2)*beta2*exp(-2*lambdaL*(3-2))
mu4<-4-choose(3,1)*beta1*exp(-1*lambdaL*(4-1))-choose(3,2)*beta2*exp(-2*lambdaL*(4-2))-choose(3,3)*beta3*exp(-3*lambdaL*(4-3))
mu5<-5-choose(4,1)*beta1*exp(-1*lambdaL*(5-1))-choose(4,2)*beta2*exp(-2*lambdaL*(5-2))-choose(4,3)*beta3*exp(-3*lambdaL*(5-3))-choose(4,4)*beta4*exp(-4*lambdaL*(5-4))
```

etc

```
lambdaL<-0.5
```

This is my list of beta's

```
betarec(10,0.5)
 [1] 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.7869387 1.0278660 1.5510843 2.3702034 3.4694342 
4.7718938
 [9] 6.1685468 7.5667952 8.9154479
```

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't this almost the same question you [asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884411/recursive-for-loop-in-r/)? What loops have you tried?

Comment: I attempted to add a math latex image using this [resource](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php). MathJax used on [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) unfortunately does not render here on StackOverflow. Remove or adjust as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a nested *apply* call with `mapply` iteratively passing *n* and *k* args to an embedded `sapply` to loop through all successive betas from 1 to current *k* and iteratively sum the results.

**Input**

```
lambdaL <- 0.5
beta <- c(0.0000000,1.0000000,0.7869387,1.0278660,1.5510843,2.3702034,
          3.4694342,4.7718938,6.1685468,7.5667952,8.9154479)
```

**Current version**

```
mu3<-3-choose(2,1)*beta[1]*exp(-1*lambdaL*(3-1))-choose(2,2)*beta[2]*exp(-2*lambdaL*(3-2))
mu3
# [1] 2.632121
mu4<-4-choose(3,1)*beta[1]*exp(-1*lambdaL*(4-1))-choose(3,2)*beta[2]*exp(-2*lambdaL*(4-2))-choose(3,3)*beta[3]*exp(-3*lambdaL*(4-3))
mu4
# [1] 3.418404
mu5<-5-choose(4,1)*beta[1]*exp(-1*lambdaL*(5-1))-choose(4,2)*beta[2]*exp(-2*lambdaL*(5-2))-choose(4,3)*beta[3]*exp(-3*lambdaL*(5-3))-choose(4,4)*beta[4]*exp(-4*lambdaL*(5-4))
mu5
# [1] 4.405454
```

**Loop version**  *(output equivalent to previous version)*

```
mu_formula <- function(n,k) {
   n + sum(sapply(seq(k), function(i)
           -choose((n-1),i)*beta[i]*exp(-i*lambdaL*(n-i))))
}

mu_vector <- setNames(mapply(mu_formula, 3:5, 2:4), paste0("mu", 3:5))
mu_vector
#      mu3      mu4      mu5 
# 2.632121 3.418404 4.405454 

mu_list <- setNames(Map(mu_formula, 3:5, 2:4),paste0("mu", 3:5))    
mu_list
# $mu3
# [1] 2.632121

# $mu4
# [1] 3.418404

# $mu5
# [1] 4.405454
```

**Generalized Loop** *(for all betas)*

```
mu_list <- setNames(Map(mu_formula,seq_along(beta)[-1]+1,seq_along(beta)[-1]),
                    paste0("mu",seq_along(beta)[-1]+1))
mu_list

# $mu3
# [1] 2.632121

# $mu4
# [1] 3.418404

# $mu5
# [1] 4.405454

# $mu6
# [1] 5.507972

# $mu7
# [1] 6.640989

# $mu8
# [1] 7.756735

# $mu9
# [1] 8.840919

# $mu10
# [1] 9.896983

# $mu11
# [1] 10.93315

# $mu12
# [1] 11.95646
```